# Old electrical box - how to cover?

Tags: electrical, old-house

[image: Old box]

I'm replacing and old Rittenhouse doorbell transformer as part of a smart doorbell upgrade.  My problem is that the screw spacing of the cover (of which the transformer is embedded) doesn't seem to match any modern-day cover spacing.

The transformer is part of a 4" door cover; there's several joined circuits inside the box so I really don't want to have to replace the box itself.  But I can't find a cover that meets these screw holes - they are 7/8" from the opposite sides and 3/8" from the top/bottom (in the pic they are the upper right slot and the bottom left hole).  A standard 4" box cover does not line up with these holes at all.

EDIT:

The diagonal hole-to-hole measurement is 4 1/4".  Also note, my goal here is a plate with a 1/2" knockout to mount the new transformer.  I've got an existing 4" plate (that I could drill out, I presume) if that's the best way.

[image: box]

Any thoughts on what might work here?  Is this spacing called something else that I'm not searching for correctly?

Comment: Make one out of thin sheet plastic. Or buy a blank that fits and drill holes to fit.

Comment: Give the dimension directly between the mounting holes on the electrical box.

Comment: Yes, can you show us the box this was mounted to?

Comment: @MichaelKaras what do you mean by "between"? From where to where?

Comment: Center of cover hole to center of the other hole. This would be diagonal across the box between the holes that the transformer cover had mounted to.

Comment: @MichaelKaras it's 4 1/4"

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel added pic of box